# How to execute this in command line(I am using spyder)

Tags: python

Write a python program to accept 10 numbers through command line arguments and calculate the sum of prime numbers among them.
This is my question.
I tried this

```
for Number in range (1, 101):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2, (Number//2 + 1)):
        if(Number % i == 0):
            count = count + 1
            break

    if (count == 0 and Number != 1):
        print(" %d" %Number, end = '  ')
```

but this is naive and works only for given range. I want to input 10 numbers in command prompt and it should find the sum of prime numbers in my input. I tried using import sys and giving sys.args[input] but it is showing errors.
Can someone please help with this?I am just starting to learn coding.
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be this:

```
import sys

nums = sys.argv


def with_loop():
    total = 0   # to collect the prime numbers
    count = 1   # a counter for the numbers that you entered
    for i in range(10):
        num = int(input("{}. Please enter a number: ".format(count)))
        if num > 1:  # if number is larger than 1, we need to check
            for j in range(2, num):
                if (num % j) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                total += num
        elif num == 1:   # 1 is a prime number
            total += num
        else:   # otherwise the number is negative so we skip.
            pass
        count += 1
    print("\nTotal : {}".format(total))


def with_argv(nums):
    total = 0   # to collect the prime numbers
    count = 1   # a counter for the numbers that you entered
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if int(nums[i]) > 1:  # if number is larger than 1, we need to check
            for j in range(2, int(nums[i])):
                if (int(nums[i]) % j) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                total += int(nums[i])
        elif int(nums[i]) == 1:   # 1 is a prime number
            total += int(nums[i])
        else:   # otherwise the number is negative so we skip.
            pass
        count += 1
    print("\nTotal : {}".format(total))


with_loop()
with_argv(nums)
```

Comment: Thank you. what command can i use to give input directly in command prompt?

Comment: For terminal, assuming that you are in home directory you have to use something like this: `python or python3 <name_of_the_file.py> num1 num2 num3 etc` for example: `python primes.py 1 2 3 5 3 53 35 234 23 52`, But if you want to use the command prompt then you have to comment out `with_argv` and `with_loop` will run anyway since it does not require any extra input and it is already been called.  Please mark it as answer if it answers your question and don't hesitate to ask more questions if you have, happy coding.

Comment: First of all Thank you for clearing the doubt.I am getting output by executing it normally. But I tried to do the same using command line arguments for giving input using import sys but I am getting errors. Can you please elaborate on how to use this code in command line arguments.

Comment: if you want to use only the command prompt method, then comment out `# with_argv(nums)` and only `with_loop()` will execute, the loop method has a fixed length of 10, so you have to provide 10 inputs. The method `with_argv(nums)` you have to provide a number of arguments after you execute the file in terminal or powershell.

Comment: It worked with command prompt.I used with_argv(nums).Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
sum = 0
for count in range(1,11):
  sum += int(input(f'Enter number {count} : '))

print(f'Total sum : {sum}')
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I would first define a function that checks whether a number is prime or not. It would only return a Boolean and nothing else.

Then I would create two lists- one for storing all the numbers entered by a user and another for storing all the prime numbers among the numbers entered by the user. I would use my predefined function for this check.

When the list of prime numbers is ready, I would use the sum() method to find the sum of the items of the list viz. the primes numbers the user has entered.

Here is the code-

```py
def isPrime(num): #defining a function to check a given number is prime
    factors = []
    if num == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
            if (num % i == 0):
                factors.append(i)
    if len(factors) == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

numbers = [] #list for user entered numbers
primes = [] #list for prime numbers among them
print("Enter 10 numbers.\n")
for i in range(10):
    numbers.append(int(input(f'Enter number #{i + 1}:')))
#adding user inputs to numbers list

for i in numbers: #checking if the entered numbers are prime
    if isPrime(i):
        primes.append(i)

print("Sum of the prime numbers enters by the user is " + str(sum(primes)))
#sum() method adds all elements in an iterable
```

This code will do.

Spyder uses IPython Console. That is the command line referred in the question. So, if you run the code in Spyder, the IPython console will run this program.